# Render a form with some join entity

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 3 entities:
Customer 
Contract (every Customer have one or more Contract, a Contract is only for one customer: so there is a OneToMany relation between Customer and Contract)
Invoice (every Invoice refer to one or more Contract, every Contract have one or more Invoice: so there is a ManyToMany relation between Contract and Invoice).

Now I want to render Invoice form with checkbox. I write:

```
->add('contracts',null, array(
'multiple'  => true,
'expanded'  => true
 ))
```

in InvoiceFormType but I get all contracts not only a specific Customer.

How to do it?

Thanks in advance.
v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't give `null` as a form type. Use your own `contractsType` instead:

```
$builder->add('contracts', new ContractsType(), array(
     'multiple' => true,
     'expanded' => true
));
```

[See the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) for more information.

Comment: Not correct. Using a `null` value force form type guessing. See at [http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#field-type-guessing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#field-type-guessing).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using the query builded into form.

At this link a http://sunzhen.blogspot.it/2012/09/symfony2-custom-query-in-entity-field.html

So:

```
 'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($customer) {
    $q=$er->createQueryBuilder('c')
          ->where('c.customer= :customer')
          ->setParameter('customer', $customer);

    return $q;
}
```